# How to connect a Vagrant Kubernetes cluster to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, vagrant

I have my own Kubernetes cluster (not AKS) made of several vagrant VMs. I have one VM for the Master and 2 others for the worker nodes.

I'm working with Azure DevOps Pipeline and I would like to deploy my docker container to this Kubernetes cluster.

There is the task `Deploy to Kubernetes`, but it seems to be only for an AKS cluster.

Is there a way to connect the pipeline with my own cluster ?

I've tried to add a new Service Connection for Kubernetes using the kubeconfig (`~/.kube/config` ?) but I was not able to verify the connection from Azure DevOps. I guess I need to do something on the VMs to make it reachable from internet and allow the connection. How can I do that ?

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a kubernetes service connection and reference that connection in the release pipeline by picking kubernetes service connection (instead of Azure Resource Manager). Your cluster should be oppublicly accessible.

[image]